# Disable CSS settings for element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Since `<select size="5"><option>...</option></select>` is broken on WebView/Android (it is ignoring the size attribute), I have to emulate this element using divs and buttons.

However, both the HTML code and CSS are generated automatically, so that I do not have direct access to those. All I can do is to use JavaScript to modify the HTML DOM inside WebView.

Now since the options are displayed using buttons, those buttons are affected by global CSS settings, which is nonsense in this case. The buttons should look like the options in a standard browser on a PC, i.e. just plain text on white background and no fancy borders etc. I need to get rid of the div/buttons CSS settings so that I can apply the CSS settings of select/option on the emulated elements.

So what is the simplest way of getting rid of all CSS settings from the global stylesheet for the elements generated by the JavaScript code?

Comment: If this is your project, can you not add your own CSS to overwrite it and/or change the assigned classes of the button on the fly using JavaScript? or does the tool that auto generates the CSS offer a way to influence the generated CSS?

Comment: No, that's not possible. I have no influence on the HTML and CSS code that comes in. I need to find a generic workaround for the <select size....> bug in WebView and rewriting it to divs and buttons using JavaScript is the only solution I have found so far but now I am stuck with global CSS settings that need to be removed.